# WSDL webservice in ios development

Tags: ios, wsdl

I am new to web services even after watching a lot of videos and reading a large number of tutorials on WSDL I am unable to understand how to get URL for a method of web service from WSDL. the WSDL file I am provided with is this http://caracal.simform.local:55137/Survely.DataServices.MemberServices.svc?wsdl I want to call all user of this web service. Can somebody explain that how to extract exact url for a web service/web service method from a WSDL file and how to pass parameters to a web service (in this particular case I want to call login). All the tutorials I watched tells that service tag of WSDL file has an address tag which tells about the url of the service but this WSDL does not contains one.

One last thing, can I call this service with soap, even soap is not used in binding. And what if I want to call it using HTTP GET / HTTP POST method, how parameters will be provided.

My main concern is how to get url of a web service / web service method from WSDL? The platform for which I want to use it is IOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve all these questions is to generate the code using wsdl2objc http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/ See the tutorial how to use the generated code.

Comment: I don't know if it is just a problem with my web service but wsdl2objc has a number of errors when creating the objc files. It couldn't create the files.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with http://sudzc.com. It allows you to pick ARC/non-ARC implementation. [WSDL2Objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/downloads/list) is another alternative, but it hasn't been updated for a while, unlike sudzc which is still maintained.

Comment: sudz.com is a paid solution

Comment: Do you have its membership ?